# Execute PHP in Ubuntu 18.04 crontab

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron, digital-ocean

I cannot get a PHP script to execute in crontab

Ubuntu 18.04

PHP 7.3

Nginx webserver on a Digital Ocean

Edit:

```
sudo nano /etc/crontab
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

I have tried the following combinations and other variations using root as the user and cannot get the php script to run

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/forge/laravel/public/cron/account_balances.php
* * * * * php /home/forge/laravel/public/cron/account_balances.php
* * * * * forge /usr/bin/php /home/forge/laravel/public/cron/account_balances.php >> /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * forge php /home/forge/laravel/public/cron/account_balances.php >> /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sudo -u www-data php /home/forge/laravel/public/cron/account_balances.php >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The script runs fine in the browser and updates some rows in a mysql database so I know if cron is executing it. I check the logs and do not see any errors:

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep cron
```

I read somewhere that it may be a permission issue running the cron since i'm using Nginx?

Comment: Don't run as root, run as an unprivileged user. (Not via sudo, just under that user's own cron.) nginx doesn't matter, since you're invoking PHP directly and not via a URL. First make sure you can run the script from the command line via just `/path/to/php /path/to/script.php`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky running from forge user from terminal doesn't do anything. The file doesn't execute and I get no error. I changed the path to the script with a random character and it says "no such file..." so obviously the path is correct

Comment: Ok, well cron is just a timer to run command line scripts, so you can't expect it to work under cron until you get it working from the command line. Turn error_reporting to max and enable display_errors to see what's wrong.

Comment: @AlexHowansky understood. I think I'm onto the issue. The php file was only read and write. I did find * -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 # for directories
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644 # for files and the php script executes from terminal

Comment: OK now run `crontab -e` as the forge user to edit that user's crontab, and put in the command that worked from the command line, preferably with full paths to everything. When you save the edit session, the new commands go active automatically, so you don't need to restart cron.

Comment: @AlexHowansky if I cd into the directory and run 'php account_balances.php' it works. If I cd to root of server and then do 'php /full/path' or '/usr/bin/php /full/path' I get nothing. Thinking it has to do with laravel or forge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue.

First the php script that I was executing from the command line didn't have correct permissions. Fixed by running

```
find * -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 # for directories 
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644 # for files
```

Second I had a require_once path error in my php file. The script worked fine from the browser but not through the command line.

Change from:

```
require_once ("../libs/php_sdk/config.php");
```

To:

```
require_once (__DIR__ . "/../libs/php_sdk/config.php");
```